# Boost::python with ACE , C++ ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost-python, ace

I am trying to have interface for C++ library for python using `boost::python`, my C++ code is using `ACE` , now when I include following code

```
#ifdef BUILD_PYTHON_EXT
  #include <boost/python.hpp>
  using namespace boost::python;
#endif
```

it is giving me  following error

```
1>E:\thirdparty\ace.6.1.0_versioned_vc10\ace/ACE.h(150): error C2872: 'ssize_t' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'E:\thirdparty\ace.6.1.0_versioned_vc10\ace/os_include/sys/os_types.h(126) : int ssize_t'
1>          or       'E:\thirdparty\boost_1_51_0\boost/python/ssize_t.hpp(15) : boost::python::ssize_t'
```

How do i resolve this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should not use using directive. Use `namespace python = boost::python` or something else. Or, you should include ACE headers, or something that include ACE headers before `using namespace boost::python;`, but first is preferable.